# For Loop Right Pyramid

Tags: java, for-loop

```
    Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
    int rjbnum1;

    System.out.print("The Input is: ");

    rjbnum1=x.nextInt();
       for (int i = rjbnum1; i > 0; i--) {
          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("\t"+ i);
            }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

> I am having a hard time with this oh :'( i need help my output is

```
5  5  5  5  5
4  4  4  4
3  3  3
2  2
1
```

> But i want my output to be<

```
            5
         4  4
      3  3  3
   2  2  2  2
1  1  1  1  1
```

> But i'm having a problem with my logical brain hahaha it took me 3hrs trying this .

Comment: yes yes the output that i want is that it?

Comment: yeah its 1,2,3,4,5 typo error

Comment: then edit your question

Comment: done i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int rjbnum1 = 5;

for (int i = rjbnum1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= rjbnum1; j++) {
        if (j >= i) {
            System.out.print("\t" + i);
        } else {
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output**

```
                5
            4   4
        3   3   3
    2   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Cool this is what i really want .. i can't believe it i almost got there but i removed the if else because it's giving me an error .. now i see how it works thanks man

Comment: Sure, glad i could help!

Comment: no @CoolNeriko you have to accept my answer, it seams that this answer is the correct so accept this not my answer

Comment: o cmon guys xD it's making me nervous with you

Answer (score 1):

Add an if condition after the two for loops. The if condition should check if the value of j in the inner loop is greater or equal to the outer loop's i value and then print the value of i inside the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("The Input is: ");

int rjbnum1=scan.nextInt();

for (int x = 1; x <= rjbnum1; x++)
{
System.out.println();

for(int i = x;i<rjbnum1; i++)
System.out.print(" ");

for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
System.out.print(x);
}
}}
```

**OUTPUT**
'The Input is: 6

```
     1
    22
   333
  4444
 55555
666666
```

Comment: Cool thanks it works just the way i want it ^^ i hope you can help me more my next will be i need to make it pyramid and a vertical pyramid but the same number format